# Sublime text3, a file icon webpack icons

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime text 3 on mac, and no matter what i do with A file icons plugins 
webpack icons is only showing if the file name has the word config

```
webpack.config.js
```

but if the file name is anything else, the icon is just a normal js file

```
webpack.dev.js
wepback.prod.js
```

webpack.dev.js and webpack.prod.js are just showing as a regular js icon

i reinstalled the plugin, still same issues, even reinstalled sublime couple of times
when i try to revert it i'm getting this error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that *A File Icon's* **Webpack Icon** only works if the file extensions are:

- "webpack.config.js"
- "webpack.config.babel.js"
- "webpack.dev.js"
- "webpack.mix.js"

Now, To make it work for your custom extensions as in your case for **"wepback.prod.js"** you will have to mannualy add this file extention into the *A File Icon's* **icons.json** file.

To do this follow the steps:

1. Install a sublime package called **PackageResourceViewer**.
2. Open the **Command Pelette** window with ctrl+shift+p.
3. Type **PackageResourceViewer: Extract Package** & click it. (This will help us to extact sublime packages).
4. Select ***A File Icon's*** from the list and click **Start Extraction**. (This will extract the *A File Icon's* packge and place it into the sublime's Packages folder)
5. Once extracted, open **preferences** -> **Browse Packages**.
6. Navigate to **A file Icon/icons/icons.json**
7. Open the **icons.json** file in sublime text and search for **"file_type_webpack"** inside the file.
8. Inside the **"file_type_webpack"** object there will be a property called **"extensions"**.
9. Now inside this property you can add your **"webpack.prod.js"** custom file extension.

Once added, save the file and restart sublime text.

Now ***A File Icon's*** will show the **Webpack Icon** for the "webpack.prod.js" file extension!!

---

**Note:** If you are using **zzz A File Icon zzz** then you can do the following:

1. **open preferences** -> **Browse Packages.**
2. Navigate to **zzz A File Icon zzz**/**aliases**/
3. Inside the aliases folder, open the file named **JavaScript (Webpack).sublime-syntax** inside sublime text.
4. Once opened, there will be a property called **"file_extensions"** & inside here you can add your **"webpack.prod.js"** file extension & this will fix your problem!!